# entity-value object, one to many relationship using entity framework fluent api

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have employee Entity with property Jobs as foreign key

```
public class Employee 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

and Job (Shared Value Object in DDD)

```
public class Job 
{
    public Guid Code { get; set; }
}
```

the Code property isn't unique itself and i should include Employee_Id column in Jobs table in database to be unique. but i don't want Employee_Id be in model.

using fluent api i used HasMany method on employee (as following) then Employee_Id was included in Jobs table

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasMany(e => e.Jobs);
```

but i cannot became it primary key. is there any way doing this?

I know in ddd matter probably i should define a relation table between Employee and Job.

Comment: I dont understand your problem, you have a relationship between Employee and Jobs, your mapping created the relationship on the database, but you dont want the ID of jobs in your model? That doesn't make sence, since the the meaning of the "model" is to be a model of your database, your entity in other words, so it should reflect your database columns. Please clarify whats the problem

Comment: yes, Exactly. a column in Jobs table but not in Job class, and make it PK.